# mono -> MonoDevelop f# 64 bit

Tags: mono

I have ubuntu 16.04 and monodevlop editor, I have added AnyCpu option and trying to compile f# code , when I check the exe it is 32 bit, I have ubuntu 64 bit.
When I compile the same code on windows using xamarin and AnyCpu option I can see in task manager that its not 32 bit exe. So it works in windows but , anycpu option for monodevlop is not giving 64 bit exe in ubuntu.
Any idea what I should do to get 64 bit exe as output
Mono Version is 4.6.2 on ubuntu.

Regards,

Amit Bhagwat

Comment: Amit, stop adding comments to your own question, just update the question instead and remove your comments.

Comment: Hi, how did you set xamarin to use mono64 as the runtime. Would it work for visualbasic, i think when I run my application in the xamarin studio it's using the mono 32bit runtime instead of mono64 bit runtime. which caused my application to fail. As I have a library that only works with 64bit library

Comment: Hi Shuliyey. Xamarin 64 bit option available for c# for f# i compile same code using visual studio 64 bit option i used vs2015 but i think 2013 should also work try vs to compile for 64 bit for vb the exe should work with mono/ ubuntu  Regards.Amit Bhagwat